# Where can I find information about car PIDs?

Tags: engine, electrical, battery, sensor

i'm doing a research and i can't find voltage information from the car sensors, where do you find such information?

finding the voltage range would help a lot.

Comment: Check the data sheets from the sensor manufacturers.

Comment: Most all manufacturers publish a factory service manual for each vehicle that details this. Which car is this ?

Answer (score 0):

Generally technical information like what you are asking are not available easily as most of them are OEM proprietary information. if you can access the repair manual of the vehicle model, then you may get some info. In some cases, if you get the part number of the component, then supplier of the component may have provided some information online. the last method would be to directly test on the vehicle and get the information directly.

Hint: Most of the sensors in vehicle have power supply of 5V or 12V